# Compiling SQLite RTREE in MSVC?

Tags: sqlite, visual-c++

I need to compile the rtree extension for SQLite from source code. The readme includes these instructions:

> The easiest way to compile and use the RTREE extension is to build
>     and use it as a dynamically loadable SQLite extension. To do this
>     using gcc on *nix:
>
> ```
> gcc -shared rtree.c -o libSqliteRtree.so
> ```
>
> You may need to add "-I" flags so that gcc can find sqlite3ext.h
>     and sqlite3.h. The resulting shared lib, libSqliteRtree.so, may be
>     loaded into sqlite in the same way as any other dynamicly loadable
>     extension.

Problem I'm having is that I'm on Windows, not Linux, and so need to use MSVC. I tried:

```
cl rtree.c -link -out:libSqliteRtree.so
```

This gave `cannot open include file` errors until I found the various `.h` files it was complaining about and moved them into the same directory. Now, however, it's gotten to:

> /out:rtree.exe
>   -out:libSqliteRtree.so
>   rtree.obj
>      Creating library libSqliteRtree.lib and object libSqliteRtree.exp
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

I admit I have pretty much zero clue what I'm doing in a compiler, and I'm not sure where to go from here to resolve its problem. Am I "translating" the compiler flags correctly from GCC to MSVC? What else can I tweak to try to get the SQLite extension out of the source code? Should I beg a favor from a developer on ateam with a Linux server and ask them to do it for me?

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html

Comment: @Shawn that was the missing piece I needed, awesome. If you want to answer I'll be able to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shawn for commenting to look at the [SQLite Run-Time Loadable Extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) documentation, which had more information in it:

> To compile on Windows using MSVC, a command similar to the following will usually work:
>
> ```
> cl YourCode.c -link -dll -out:YourCode.dll
> ```

So for my situation: `cl rtree.c -link -dll -out:libSqliteRtree.dll` worked.